# android - Dynamically add row to a table with data from the text entry

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to capture data from the text entry and add the data to the table layout and refresh the layout. When I click "Add" button, a dialog pops up with the text field. After I enter anything and click "OK", it should create a new row and refresh the view.

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/table"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="#f7ad5d"
             android:weightSum="1">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <Button android:layout_width="100px" android:text="Add" android:textSize="13px" android:layout_height="50px" android:id="@+id/add_button"></Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000" android:text="  My List"></TextView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog();
        }
    });
}

    private void update() {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("New Entry");
    tr.addView(tv);

    table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}


    /**
 * Show a dialog
 */
private void showDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            update();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

For now, I am not capturing data from the text entry. I am just trying to add a dummy data to the table layout with dummy data, but i keep getting "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." at this line,

table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

I am a beginner to android development. It would be great if someone can give me some tips about this.

Thanks.

Comment: The code looks ok.  From the link @Parth_90 provided, they are setting id on the rows they add.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your update method:

```
private void update() {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText("New Entry");
    tr.addView(tv);

    table.addView(tr);
}
```

Important things are:

- When you add a `TableRow` to a `TableLayout` use `TableLayout.LayoutParams`
- When you add a `View` to a `TableRow` use `TableRow.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

You can have look at [this](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/)

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. I checked the link. I think that I am following the same logic. no?

Comment: I guess something to do with the dialog. I haven't tried it for myself yet..just see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674413/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent) question

Answer (score 0):

I assume `tr` is a variable that you are reusing.  You need to create a new `TableRow` for every row you want to add.

If you want to do the table and row definition in XML, you can do with the following approach.

First, create 2 layout files, one for your table and one for your table row, such as:

table_header.xml

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/TableHeader">
    <TextView style="@style/TableRowHeaderCell" android:text="@string/index" />
    <TextView style="@style/TableRowHeaderCell" android:text="@string/count" />
</TableRow>
```

table_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/TableRow">
    <TextView style="@style/NumberInTable" android:id="@+id/textViewIndex" />
    <TextView style="@style/NumberInTable" android:id="@+id/textViewCount" />
</TableRow>
```

The added benefit is that styles can be applied to your table and rows.

From here, in order to add the row to the table, you need to initialize the table with the following code:

```
_tableLayoutResults = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutResults);
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_header, _tableLayoutResults);
```

To add a new row, you'd use something like:

```
// create the row with the xml layout
final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);

// set values in row
((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textViewIndex)).setText("someText");

// finally add the row
_tableLayoutResults.addView(row);
```

Comment: I think that I am creating a new tr.

Comment: I added a scaled down example from what I've done in the past.  I hope that helps.