# Android Alert Dialog won't dismiss

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i make AlertDialog before some action and the AlertDialog won't dismissed after the action.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    View pbview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, null);
                    builder.setView(pbview);

                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.create().show();
//do some stuff

builder.create().dismiss();
}
```

by the way my AlertDialog doesn't have any button.
i want to make AlertDialog without button and automatically dismissed when the action is over.

EDIT: i changed the instance name.

Comment: use  same instance of AlertDialog on which you are calling show method for dismiss in you case try as:  
`Dialog dialog=dlgAlert.create().show(); dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: do u want dismiss the dialog box after complete some action am i correct ? if yes means try asynchronous task in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agree with @ρяσѕρєя K
 make an instance of AlertDialog and modify your code as.

```
  AlertDialog alert ;

 alert =  dlgAlert.create();
        alert.show();
        //do some stuff

                alert.dismiss();
```

and if you want a custom dialog then you can use code like this :-

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button


        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Logcat says: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I edit my answer, I did not notice that you are inflating a view. you can use setContentView() method.

Comment: Does the **AlertDialog.Builder** have **setContentView();** method??

Answer (score 0):

only

```
dlgAlert.dismiss();
```

thats it :)

Comment: The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
dlgAlert.dismiss();
```

or

```
dlgAlert.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create the `AlertDialog` you want...

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create();
```

Then try `show`,`dismiss` on your `AlertDialog`

```
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: its working if i used setMessage, but i'm using setView. Logcat said The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: you are adding the view to the AlertDialog twice..check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674413/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent