# Unable to add DialogFragment to Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have tried multiple solutions posted previously, but none work for my case. My activity starts a non-UI fragment, which then shows a dialog fragment. I am using setTargetFragment for communicating between fragment and dialogfragment. But I keep on getting the error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

**My code :** (I am using support library for all fragments/activities)

**Activity :**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment f1 = F1.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.container, f1, "f1");   //I have previously shown a fragment in this activity, so replacing
ft.commit();


Fragment (F1):


 public static F1 newInstance() {
            F1 f = new StartupOptionalServicesFragment();
            f.setRetainInstance(true);
            return f;
        }


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DialogFragment d1 = D1.newInstance();
        d1.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        d1.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "d1");

    }
```

DialogFragment (D1)

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        builder = new AutoScrollAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity());
    } else {
        builder = new AutoScrollAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_d1, null, false);

    TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mytitle);
    message.setText("Agree ?");

    builder.setView(view).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            callback = (D1Callback)getTargetFragment();
            if (callback != null) callback.selection(true);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(view).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            callback = (D1Callback)getTargetFragment();
            if (callback != null) callback.selection(false);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;

}
```

Comment: On what line to you get the error? Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the specified child already has a parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674413/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent)

Comment: Stupid error... I wascalling setView twice (while setting positive and negative button)